# How does one specify a network interface/local IP address to use for one's "no VPN" browser profile?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, openvpn, bypass, palemoon

I run Pale Moon on Windows 10. I'm always connected to a VPN using OpenVPN. If I connect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in Pale Moon (or any program), it uses the VPN connection. So far, so good.

However, many privacy-disrespecting websites completely block my requests or give fake error messages when trying to register accounts if they detect that the visitor doesn't want to be fully tracked (that is, if a VPN is used). For example, it's impossible to register an account on any dating website, or Github, or just about any major service at all anymore.

For this reason, I'm forced to find a way to use my "plain" home connection upon request. It's technically possible if I use a specific network interface (specified by a local IP address on Windows), so I am able to make a manual cURL request which bypasses the VPN by specifying this network interface/address for the cURL request. But that's not useful for actually browsing as a human.

Browsers/Pale Moon appears to have no such feature to specify a different network interface/address. I need to make a Pale Moon profile which always uses this network interface/address, called "Bypass VPN". But it seems impossible?

Yes, Pale Moon/browsers in general allow you to set a *proxy*, but not a *network interface/address*.

It is not an option to "disconnect the VPN" since that would break everything I'm doing through it. I only have one computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to bypass the VPN for a specific website, this is done at the
level of Windows, not in the browser.

Here is how to do this:

- Find the address of your non-VPN gateway. You may find it by running
  `route print`. It may look like `192.168.1.1` and be on the line where
  "Destination" is "0.0.0.0". If unsure which one, stop the VPN for a simpler view.
- Find the IP address of the website, for example by running in CMD the command
  `ping website`. Let's say the address is `91.250.85.234`.
- In a Command Prompt that is Run as Administrator, enter the following command:

  ```
    route add 91.250.85.234 192.168.1.1
  ```

There exist also various methods to entirely bypass VPN blocking,
so you could use the VPN for all sites without needing the above method.
For a list of the methods, see the article:
[How to bypass VPN blocks & make your VPN undetectable](https://cybernews.com/how-to-use-vpn/bypass-vpn-blocks/).

Reference:
[route command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008).

Comment: 1. Websites seldom have a single IP address, and they change all the time. 2. This is definitely not what I want.

Comment: Well-known websites don't change IPs that often. Perhaps some other answer will come up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 3rd party tool called [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) that would allow you to bind PaleMoon to use another gateway or specific interface. Read the page carefully, it mentions specific exceptions for browsers like Chrome (where it no longer works) and Firefox Compatibility (setting a flag, which will most likely be the same for PaleMoon). Also read the part about DLL injection and its  possible implications!

Otherwise you're stuck with good old routing tables, which you've made clear you do not want to use.